# Two way pipe communication between parent and child

Tags: c, linux, exec, fork, pipe

I'm trying to create two-way communication between parent and child processes using 2 pipes in C.the prog1 running in child1 
I want to read 3+4+5 from prog1 after that send something to prog1 with write but I could not.
Where is the wrong?

```
/* prog1.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void
main(void){
    int FD;
unsigned int buf;
char buf[15];

printf("7+5+11=?\n");
FD=read(0,buf,10);
if(FD<0){
    perror("FAIL\n");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
     printf("TAKED:%s\n",buf);
}
```

prog2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
void ERR_SYS(const char *msg);
int
main(void){
    char buf[15];
    int pipe1[2];
    int pipe2[2];
    pid_t childpid;

    memset(buf,'\0',14);

    if(pipe(pipe1) < 0 || pipe(pipe2) < 0)
     ERR_SYS("fail_pipe");

    if((childpid = fork()) < 0)
     ERR_SYS("fail_fork");

    if(childpid==0)
    {
      dup2(pipe2[1],1);
          dup2(pipe1[0],0);
      close(pipe1[1]);
          close(pipe2[0]);
      close(pipe2[1]);
      close(pipe1[0]);
          //close(1);
          //close(0);
      execle("./prog1",NULL,NULL,NULL);
    }else{

     close(pipe1[0]);
     close(pipe2[1]);
     read(pipe2[0],buf,4); /*I hope to read 3+4+5*/
     printf("BuF::%s\n",buf);
     write(pipe1[1],"off",3);/*send {off}*/
     wait(NULL);
    }
 return 0;
 }

 void 
 ERR_SYS(const char *msg)
 {
     perror(msg);
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
```

Comment: check return values of read and write! What does it mean "I could not"? How does the program behave?

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems with your program:

1. You are not checking returned values of read, write and execle in prog2.c
2. You are sending "7+5+11=?\n" string which is 10 characters long but only expecting 4 characters ( 3+4+5 is not even four characters ).
3. Also "off" you are sending is 3 characters long but without including null termination.
4. When you read from an `fd` you will in both cases not get null terminated string and then you are trying to `printf` it. It's a quick way to undefined behaviour. Put an '\0' after the end of buffer you read from any file descriptor!
5. Especially what `read` returns is very important as it tells you how many characters were read. You should never ignore returned value of `read` (in some cases it's the same with `write` function).

Next time also provide some output of your program as it will be easier to give some help.

Comment: Additionl problem -- `printf` by default just buffers data to be written later -- you need an explicit `fflush` call to ensure its actually written.  This is what causes the program to hang -- both child and parent are blocked waiting in `read` with no data actually written by either.  But after adding `fflush` you'll run into all the other problems identified here...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't follow all your logic in setting up the pipes, so I modified and hopefully clarified your original. I should note that for whatever reason I named fd_in and fd_out from the external program's (prog1) point of view (e.g. fd_out is where prog1 is writing to, fd_in is where prog1 is reading from).

Here's the contents of my prog3.c:

```
...
#define READ_END 0
#define WRITE_END 1
void ERR_SYS(const char *msg);
int main(void) {

    char buff[15];
    char *msg = "hello";
    int fd_out[2];
    int fd_in[2];
    int nbytes;
    pid_t childpid;

    if(pipe(fd_out) < 0 || pipe(fd_in) < 0) {
            ERR_SYS("fail_pipe");
    }

    if((childpid = fork()) < 0) { 
            ERR_SYS("fail_fork");
    }

    if(childpid==0) { //child 
            //connect the write end of fd_out to stdout
            dup2(fd_out[WRITE_END], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fd_out[WRITE_END]);
            //connect the read end of fd_in to stdin
            dup2(fd_in[READ_END], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd_in[READ_END]);
            //the exec'd prog1 will inherit the streams
            execlp("./prog1", "prog1", NULL); //TODO: check return
    } else { //parent
            nbytes = write(fd_in[WRITE_END], msg, strlen(msg));
            //TODO: handle any errors from write
            nbytes = read(fd_out[READ_END],buff,sizeof(buff)-1);
            //TODO: handle any errors from read
            buff[nbytes] = '\0';
            printf("contents of buff::%s",buff);
    }
    return 0;
}
void ERR_SYS(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

And here's the contents of my prog1.c

```
int main(void){
    char buff[15];
    int nbytes;
    nbytes = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, sizeof(buff)-1);
    buff[nbytes] = '\0';
    printf("%s world\n", buff);
    return 0;
```

}