# c programming - no result on two way communication between one parent and 4 child

Tags: c, arrays, pipe

This question is an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512230/fork-with-char-array-and-qsort-resulting-child-stop-working) with modified requirements. Please refer to the link for the previous version. The major difference from the last question is that:

1. the need to have two pipes for each child process and have child parent communication to each child
2. read file contents using io redirection

I am a newcomer for pipes, and I have encounter problem. In the updated version:

1. parent distribute cards and store results in array
2. write array to responsible write end of pipe for each child process
3. each process need to read the array from responsible read end of pipe
4. produce same output as the previous version

The problem is when I run the code, it has no result. What is wrong with my code?

I intended to store all pipes for each child in a 2d array, i.e. `read_pipe[s][x]`, where s is the child process identifier and x is the file descriptors.

I have also studied [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178382/two-way-pipe-communication-between-parent-and-child), however, that question is for 1 parent 1 child, it could not solve my problem since I have 4 childs.

The initial attempt for the updated version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 51  
int main(void)
{
    int ch; 
    ssize_t rread;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0; 
    while (rread = getdelim( &line, &len, '\0', stdin) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", rread);
        printf("%s", line);
    }  
    char *array[BUFFERSIZE];
    int i=0;

    array[i] = strtok(line," ");

    while(array[i]!=NULL)
    {
        array[++i] = strtok(NULL," ");
    }
    //for (i=0; i<=BUFFERSIZE; i++)
      //  printf("\narray: %s: %d", array[i], i);
    //return 0;

    int childlimit = 4;
    int childpids[childlimit];
    int currpid, s; 
    char *buf[BUFFERSIZE];
    /** Pipe for reading for subprocess */
    int read_pipe[4][2];
    /** Pipe for writing to subprocess */
    int write_pipe[4][2];
    int n;
    char buffer[100];
    memset(buffer, '\0', 100);
    if (pipe(read_pipe) == 0 && pipe(write_pipe) == 0)
    {
      for(s=0; s<childlimit; s++){
        switch(currpid = fork()){
        case 0: 
         printf("Child : %d, pid %d : ", s, getpid() );
         close(read_pipe[s][1]);
         close(write_pipe[s][0]);
         close(write_pipe[s][1]);
         while((n = read(read_pipe[s][0], buf, BUFFERSIZE))>0){
             printf("<child> %s", buf[n]); //no output
         } 
         close(read_pipe[s][0]);
         return 0;
        case -1:
                printf("Error when forking\n");
                break;
        default:
                // in the father
                childpids[s] = currpid; 
                // store current child pid
                close(read_pipe[s][0]);
                close(read_pipe[s][1]);
                close(write_pipe[s][1]);
                int j,tt;
                for(j=0; j<BUFFERSIZE; j+=4){
                    buf[tt] = array[j];
                    tt++;
                }
                write(write_pipe[s][0],buf,BUFFERSIZE);
                close(write_pipe[s][0]);
                break;
        }
    }   
    //wait for all child created to die
    waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
    printf("Father : %d childs created\n", s);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think that `pipe(read_pipe)` will do when you declare `int read_pipe[4][2];` while it is expected to receive an `int fildes[2]`? IMHO, only the first pipe will be initialized.

Comment: plus even if the pipes were set up correctly, the code is not passing anything down `read_pipe` from the parent - it's putting it down `write_pipe` which the child closes completely.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @Chris, Please provide an answer on how to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `pipe()` takes an int array of size 2 which equate to both ends of a pipe. You read on filedes[0] and write on filedes[1]. Here is an example of what using `pipe()` and `fork()` together looks like.

```
int filedes[2];
if(pipe(filedes)==0)
  {
  pid_t childpid=fork();
  if(childpid==0)
     {
     close(filedes[1]); // close write end of the pipe
     read(filedes[0],buf,BUFFERSIZE);
     close(filedes[0]);
     exit(0);
     }
  else if(childpid!=-1)
     {
     close(filedes[0]);
     write(filedes[1],buf,BUFFERSIZE);
     close(filedes[1]);
     wait(NULL);
     }
  else
     {
     printf("Fork failed\n");
     }
  }
```

Comment: do this example still be correct when there is multiple children as I mentioned in the question? how can I modify it to make it suitable for multiple children?

Comment: Given that your code is only ever dealing with one child at a time, yes it should be fine for what you're doing - just needs the read & write code fleshed out as per your requirements.